# How do I toggle non contiguous selection in Krita?

Tags: selections, krita

I want to select more than just the existing region, but all regions in that layer. How is it done?

[image]

It is not the same as "Add" as I do not want to click multiple times for this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try what is called **Similar Color Selection Tool** it is not contiguous and as the name say it will select taking the color similarity in consideration, it allow for fuzziness adjustments too.

The Icon is like this: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously select all isn't what you want, because it selects also unpainted areas.

You can use Contiguous area selection tool or Similar color selection tool to select the emptiness or the background color around your painted areas and then invert the selection in the Select menu or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I. Similar color selection tool takes also unpainted areas inside the painted shapes.

You should make the first selection with fuzziness=1, shrink and feather=0 until you are sure that inversion behaves as you want with them. You should need no fuzziness if you select unpainted area. You can goto select menu and shrink and feather after inverting the selection.

If your painted areas are in separate layers, uncheck "Limit to current layer" in the tool options. That's not available for Similar color selector, only for Contiguous area selector. Temporarily close unwanted layers in the layers panel to prevent them affecting the selection.

**Another option** is to select Opaque in the select menu. It works if your unpainted areas are transparent and painted areas are fully opaque in the current layer. Partially transparent areas will be selected partially, like feathered.

Photoshop style selection by clicking in the layers panel do not work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using the previous help and it's perfect:
So for the magic wand tool under Continuous Area Selection click replace. Fuzzy=1, Grow/shrink=-2px, Feathering radius=6px. Don't check anti-aliasing but do check limit to the current layer. When you outline color around your line art it selects that area great and then you can use the bucket tool.
Just in case my bucket tool settings are Threshold= 8, Grow selection=0px, Feathering Radius=0. The other boxes are unchecked.